# Can RGB and RGBA be converted to each other?

Tags: python, colors, rgb, rgba

I have a RGB image, and I want to convert it to RGBA to get alpha channels. It's likely to convert RGB to HSV to get V channel. but now i want to get Alpha channel from RGBA. Can RGB and RGBA be converted to each other?

Comment: What do you mean. e.g. if I have rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.5) and background(255, 255, 255), you want something like rgb(191, 191, 191)? And the contrary function? (which it is may not be unique, so you may want to prefer maximum transparency?) The maximum opacity is trivial: rgb(x, y, z) == rgba(x, y, z, 1). I think you should improve your question explain exactly what it is your problem, and what sort of solution do you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RGB represented in RBGA is just the same RGB values with A=max.
For example, in CSS colors, rgb(123,45,67) = rgba(123,45,67,1) since the maximum alpha is 1.

However, RGBA cannot be directly converted back to RGB (except when everything is with A=max). The actual colour displayed depends on what is behind it (i.e. the background).